# How would I integrate the contourArea() function in my OpenCV program?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour, area

My code is for the purposes of detecting various shapes based off the number of vertices they have. I've finally accomplished that and it works perfectly for simple images like shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB6YR.png However for this thresh image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sizci.png it creates hundreds of shapes because of all the little pixels. Now I know enough of OpenCV to know there's eroding and dilating, but it seems like the best approach would be to exclude contours whose area is below a certain pixel count, however I don't know how to integrate the contourArea() function into my code such that it would work.
Here is my current code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo/photo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img;
Mat img_gray;


void contour_finder(int, void*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    img = imread("C:/Users/wyndr_000/Documents/VisualStudio2013/Projects/OpenCV_Template/OpenCV_Template/testpic.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    contour_finder(0, 0);

    waitKey();
}

void contour_finder(int, void*)
{
Mat img_thresh;
Mat drawn_contours;
threshold(img_gray, img_thresh, 183, 255, 2);
imshow("Thresh Image", img_thresh);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Point> result;

findContours(img_thresh, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// Find a way to filter it out based on Area

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), result, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

//  if (contourArea(result) < 49)
    //{
        if (result.size() == 3)
        {
            cout << "TRIANGLE\n";
        }
        else if (result.size() == 4)
        {
            cout << "QUADRILATERAL\n";
        }
        else if (result.size() == 5)
        {
            cout << "PENTAGON\n";
        }
        else if (result.size() == 6)
        {
            cout << "HEXAGON\n";
        }
        else if (result.size() == 10)
        {
            cout << "STAR\n";
        }
        else if (result.size() == 12)
        {
            cout << "PLUS-SIGN\n";
        }
//  }
}


/* drawn_contours = Mat::zeros(img_thresh.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(drawn_contours, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
}
namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawn_contours); */
}
```

You'll notice where I declare what different amounts of vertices indicate, I have a commented contourArea function, because that's where I imagined it would go.

Comment: Your `if (contourArea(result) < 49)` seems OK. What problem are you encountering with?

Comment: Well, it builds correctly, and runs, but it doesn't return any shapes (in the cmd that is) so it's saying none of the previously found shapes are larger than 49 pixels. I even changed it to 1 pixel and it still doesn't say any names... I don't understand. (if you want a picture, just imagine the first imgur link with nothing in the cmd).

Comment: Well turns out I had that the wrong comparing sign, it should be greater than so it looks for shapes greater than 49 pixels. thanks for making me focus a bit more on that part!

Comment: @Wyndrix, could you anwer your own question with the explanation and accept it so it does not appear on the unanswered list?